# React Class component render function with props and state as parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just wondering, why render function in React Class component doesn't get props and state as it's parameters.

This

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render({ prop1, prop2 }, { state1, state2 }) {

  }
}
```

would be in my oppinion way prettier than this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { prop1, prop2 } = this.props;
    const { state1, state2 } = this.state;
  }
}
```

Preact does pass both props and state to render functions.
Is there any good reason that React doesn't?

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 1):

React components and elements are immutable.  When a render occurs, it already has all the data it needs in the class, whether it be state or props.

You can read about that here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element

So, what this allows react to do is ensure it has everything existing in the component when it comes time to render it.  No worrying about passing in the proper parameters, because you already have everything available in the `this` scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a member of the Facebook team however I'm assuming it's because of monomorphism. Basically, when a function accepts the exact same parameters the VM doesn't have to recompile the function. This is important to React because `props` and `state` are so volatile to change.. There's a great explanation of monomorphism [here](http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html).